# Is it possible to set Blender Selection Mode to left click selection via Python?

Tags: python

I was wondering if it would be possible to change Blender to left click selection mode via Python. The tooltip in 2.72 says the Datapath is UserPreferencesInput.select_mouse, but I am a bit lost on how to get there. Is it part of the keymap definition? If so, can it be changed via Python at all?

I am working on an add-on that changes quite a few hotkeys of Blender around in conjunction with Pie-Menus.

Any help here is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The full path to the current user preference is

```
bpy.context.user_preferences.inputs.select_mouse = 'LEFT'
```

Comment: fantastic! found it myself a minute ago, but in fact your answer even came before that!